# NativeScript - How to convert xml layout to native view?

Tags: view, nativescript

I'm trying to create dialog with a custom layout view and when I try do this:

```
import app = require('application'); 
import { GridLayout } from 'ui/layouts/grid-layout';

const dialog = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(app.android.currentContext);
const layout = new GridLayout();

dialog.setView(layout);
```

So I got the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot convert object to Landroid/view/View;
```

I tried change to:

```
dialog.setView(layout.android);
```

And

```
dialog.setView(layout.nativeView);
```

And the dialog is displayed empty.

How I can convert a NativeScript UI Object to a native android View?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't access `nativeView` or `android` property of nativescript view without adding it to Visual UI tree. when nativescript view is added to UI tree then it gets valid values for `android` and `nativeView`.

so you have to do something like this:

```
let container= <StackLayout>this.page.getViewById("stackContainer");
let layout = new GridLayout();
let label = new Label();
label.text = "Custom Alert working";
layout.addChild(label)
container.addChild(layout)
```

now you will have values for `android` and `nativeView` properties of GridLayout.

but after that you will not be able to use `layout.android` or `layout.nativeView` in `setView` because it already contains parent. so workaround for this that you remove this view from container's native view.

```
let nativeView=layout.nativeView;
container.nativeView().removeView(nativeView)
dialog.setView(nativeView).show();
```

also note that removing child from container will also reset child's android property to null. that's why we are saving reference to `nativeView` variable.

here is working playground demo is you need help:https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=4610ET